# How to get the status of any service in a sh script on centos 7?

Tags: linux, shell, centos7

I am trying to get the service status (for a /bin/sh script) and start it if is not running.
I found some scripts, but does not work for centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

There are, as usual, multiples ways to do this. Just one example, that check if postfix is running:

```
#!/bin/sh
PID=`cat /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid`
# echo $PID

PS=`/bin/ps axu | grep $PID | grep -v grep`

# echo $PS
if [ "$PS" = "" ]
then
    /sbin/service postfix restart
fi
```

You could use "pid" file, or try to detect if process is running (parsing output of "ps axu |grep *process_name*"), or parse output of "service *process* status" command, etc, etc.